# How to use image as icon in winforms?

Tags: winforms, forms, c#-4.0, winforms-interop

[image]I [image]

My requirement is something like attached image. 
I am designing an File editor with more options like language , copy ,paste and save. For that i tried adding icon image to menu strip.  It worked but i have limitations on size adjustment , clarity all those things.

Could anyone suggest me any option/control to achieve similar to attached image.

Thanks

Comment: A [Ribbon Control](http://fluent.codeplex.com)?

Comment: These are big images.  Menus use small images, they are not going to look very pretty after they are shrunk.  Maybe you don't actually like a menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at 2 approaches:

1. Use [Gallery in Ribbon Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd742868%28v=vs.85%29.aspx);
2. Shrink an image to 32 X 32 or 16 X 16 and you will get a reasonable looking icon. You can try this [site](http://www.simpleimageresizer.com/) to shrink you image resources.